# Expected Value Problem including permutations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, expected-value

Please help!

Let F denote some permutation that maps from A to A. Where A={1,2,...2n} is a set. For such a permutation, F, let p denote the number of indices i, belonging to A, such that $F(i) > 2i$

Suppose that the permutation F is chosen randomly, from the set of all permutations of the set F, meaning that each permutation is equally liked to be chosen.

How would I go about calculating the expected value of p. I have no idea even how to go about it.

Comment: Linearity of expectation is going to be particularly powerful here.  What is the chance that $F(i)>2i$ for a *specific* $i$?  If even that is too general a problem for you to think about right away, then how about answering it for a few small cases for $i$... what is the probability that $F(1)>2$?  That $F(2)>4$?  That $F(3)>6$?

Comment: How is linearity of expectation applied here - I am confused? Thanks

Comment: by adding together the individual respective probabilities of each individual index as having the property mentioned you get the expected number of the total number of indices having the property mentioned.

Comment: Could you explain further please?

Comment: What is there to explain?  If $X$ is a random variable and you notice that $X$ can be rewritten as $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_n$ where each of the $X_i$ are indicator random variables, random variables who take values only $0$ or $1$, then $E[X]=E[X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_n] = Pr(X_1=1)+Pr(X_2=1)+\dots+Pr(X_n=1)$.  It is one of the most common uses of linearity of expectation, to make our lives tremendously easier for problems like this.  We don't actually *care* what the exact probability distribution is for $X$ since we don't need it.

Comment: Can I ask what the Random Variable $X_i$ would be for each i?

Comment: In your problem?  The random variable who takes value $1$ in the case that $F(i)>2i$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.  Hence my very first comment, leading you to try to find $Pr(X_i=1)=Pr(F(i)>2i)$

Comment: I am new to probability so taking me a while to understand things, but I studied this in-depth and now realise what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The probability that $F(i)>2i$ is $E(i)=\frac{2n-2i}{2n}$.

Then the expected value of $p$ is the sum of the $E(i)$ for $1\le i \le n-1$.

This is $\frac{1+2+ ... +n-1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{2}.$